# Include CSS and JS files in Node.js

Tags: html, css, node.js

I am learning how to use Node.js but I'm stuck. I am unable to load css
 and js files in my project. I am loading Bootstrap and Fontawesome from a CDN and they're rendering fine. As for my own custom
 css and js, they are not loading at all.

My folder file path:

folder
 index.html
 app.js
 package.json
  css
 main.css
  files
   file.pdf

app.js:

```
 var http = require('http');
     var fs = require('fs');

 //creating server
 http.createServer(function (req, res) {
   fs.readFile('index.html', function (err, html) {
     res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
     res.write(html);
     res.end();

   });
 }).listen(8080);
```

Comment: You might want to consider using expressjs. It makes it really easy to serve up static files and use nodejs for custom server side code as well. https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: If you are looking to use Node.js with CSS and JS on the client side I would suggest using Angular, which makes things like this much easier in my opinion. Anything you want to serve up you can simply include in your app's folder. Try this **sudo npm install -g @angular/cli** then create a new folder and type **ng new myApp && cd myApp && ng-serve -o**. Now find your **src/app/index.html** file and hack away!

Answer (score 9):

I would suggest you create a public directory where you should keep all your javascript, CSS, images etc.

Now in app.js file, you can add this code to make all these files available anywhere in your node.js project.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Don't forget to include path and express in your header like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
```

Now you can use your CSS/JS files wherever you want like this.

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/style.css' />
```

Here style.css is your custom CSS file. Hope this way works fine to you.

HTH Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

if your assets directory(css,js,fonts directory) on the root like below

[image]

then use this code

in **app.js**

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/')));
```

and in **.html** file import css like that

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

if your assets are under another any parent folder like that

```
public/assets/css/style.css
```

then just replace **`/`**  with `public/assets` folder like below

```
 app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public/assets')));
```

and the `<link>` tag will remain same

Answer (score 1):

There are various packages available to ease handling and creating the server.
Like `Express`, `Connect` etc.

But if you prefer plain node.js I would suggest looking at below links.

https://gist.github.com/ryanflorence/701407

http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/nodejs/serving-static-files-in-nodejs

To summarize :

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

//setting middleware
app.use(express.static(__dirname + 'public')); //Serves resources from public folder
```

Answer (score 0):

This might sound impractical but one way to achieve this without express.js is to create different server port dedicated to serving each src or href attr in your html template with their required data i.e creating a new http server for each data request and each server runs on a unique port and then set the absolute uri to of the appropriate port to each src of href attr, each port reads and supplys data from a different file. I think dis is working analogy of express.js

`app.use(express.static(__dirname + 'public'));`